# Vertical space before align environment is smaller than before displayed math

Tags: spacing, align, amsmath

The result of the following code is strange: vertical space before `align` environment is smaller than displayed math. What is the problem with `align` environment?

Edit: I want the same vertical space before and after align environments, just like other displayed formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{4pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\baselineskip}{19pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\noindent
\fbox{\makebox[\textwidth]{lazy dog}}
\begin{align*}
  \boxed{f(x) = \sin x + 1}
\end{align*}
\fbox{\makebox[\textwidth]{lazy dog}}
$$\boxed{f(x) = \sin x + 1}$$
\fbox{\makebox[\textwidth]{lazy dog}}
\[\boxed{f(x) = \sin x + 1}\]
\fbox{\makebox[\textwidth]{lazy dog}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There isn't is a problem here, *per se*. `\begin{align}`...`\end{align}` do some things different than does `\[`...`\]` (see [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)). What are you after? Should they be the same? If so, which one do you prefer?

Comment: `align` is intended to be used for multi-line, not single line, displays.

Comment: @Werner I want the same vertical space before and after align environments, just like other displayed formulas.

Comment: @Z.H.: Then you should not adjust `\lineskiplimit`.

Comment: @Werner I have updated my MWE, and there is no difference between `\[...\]` and `$$...$$` in my case. The problem is the inconsistent spaces before and after the `align` formula.

Comment: @Werner I need \lineskiplimit in my real usage. Why does it only affect `align` environments? I don't think I am using \lineskiplimint in a wrong way.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It is a MWE. The problem also exists in multi-line `align` formulas.

Comment: @Z.H.: It's because `align` uses `\lineskiplimit` and `\[`...`\]` doesn't. Check `\@display@init` in [`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx).

Comment: @Werner Could it be interpreted as `align` uses `\lineskiplimit` in a buggy way?

Comment: @Z.H. not really. _whenever_ `\lineskip` is used you get inconsistent spacing, as that is what it is for, a fallback for when consistent `\baselineskip` can not be ensured. By increasing `\lineskiplimit` you make that more likely.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I still could not understand why `align` environment needs to use \lineskiplimit. Are there any special reasons for it?

Comment: there are some comments in the code, ... `% \begin{macro}{\strut@}
% \begin{macro}{\strutbox@}
%    Next follows a special internal strut which is supposed to match
%    the height and the depth of a normal |\strut| minus
%    |\normallineskiplimit| according to M. Spivak.`

Comment: you may want to adjust `\normallineskiplimit` but having such a large value for `\lineskiplimit` seems very odd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @DavidCarlisle's comment, the problem could be fixed with

```
\normallineskiplimit=\lineskiplimit
```

[image]

Comment: it have been nice if ask David first, if he would extend his comment to the answer ...

Comment: @Zarko I have waited for the answer for one week. Apparently he is not interested in answering this question.